# Grid lines with pgfplot dashed lines disappear

Tags: pgfplots

I want to make a grid for practicing Kanji (Japanese symbols)
I want grid where each cell is divided with dashed lines. If one cell is 1cm or larger it works great. However, I want each cell to be 0.8 x0.8cm an If I choose anything smaller than 1cm it compiles but the measures are different and the there are no dashed lines. Can't upload a photo right now.. It always says error occured at imgur...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style = {dashed, Gray}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style = {solid, Black}}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[Black]
        \begin{axis}[grid = both,
                     ticks = none,
                     minor tick num = 1,
                     xmin = 0,
                     ymin = 0,
                     xmax = 17,
                     ymax = 26,
                     width = 17cm,
                     height = 26cm,
                     scale only axis]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \newpage

    \pgfplotsset{minor grid style = {dashed, Black}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style = {solid, Black}}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[Black]
       \begin{axis}[grid = both,
                 ticks = none,
                 minor tick num = 1,
                 xmin = 0,
                 ymin = 0,
                 xmax = 16,
                 ymax = 24,
                 xtick = {0, 0.8,..., 16},
                 ytick = {0, 0.8,..., 24},
                 width = 16cm,
                 height = 24cm,
                 scale only axis]
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}




\end{document}
```

Comment: There are dashed lines in the output on my machine.

Comment: @marmot also on the one on the second page? The first one is with 1 cm that works but the one on the second page I wanted with 0.8cm grid and there are no dashed lines...

Comment: What you always can do is to leave out `xtick = {0, 0.8,..., 16},` and `ytick = {0, 0.8,..., 24},`, and to add `scale=0.8` to the options of the second `tikzpicture`. You may then have to multiply `height` and `width` by 1.25 each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this suffice?

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=0.8cm,dashed] (0,0) grid (16,16);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**
I misunderstood your question, I read too quickly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
    \draw[step=0.5,dashed,gray] (0,0) grid ++(23,34);
    \draw                       (0,0) grid ++(23,34);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The Outline shouldn't be dashed. I want 0.8x0.8 cells that are divided in 4 parts with dashed lines...

Comment: @Katharina I seem to have read your question a bit too quickly. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ad hoc proposal. Use `scale`. For your convenience this answer comes with a `\ScaleFactor`, which is set to `0.8` but can be adjusted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style = {dashed, Gray}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style = {solid, Black}}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[Black]
        \begin{axis}[grid = both,
                     ticks = none,
                     minor tick num = 1,
                     xmin = 0,
                     ymin = 0,
                     xmax = 17,
                     ymax = 26,
                     width = 17cm,
                     height = 26cm,
                     scale only axis]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \newpage

    \pgfplotsset{minor grid style = {dashed, Black}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ScaleFactor}{0.8} 
\pgfplotsset{major grid style = {solid, Black}}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[Black,scale=\ScaleFactor]
       \begin{axis}[grid = both,
                 ticks = none,
                 minor tick num = 1,
                 xmin = 0,
                 ymin = 0,
                 xmax = 16/\ScaleFactor,
                 ymax = 24/\ScaleFactor,
                 width = 16cm/\ScaleFactor,
                 height = 24cm/\ScaleFactor,
                 scale only axis]
    \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I change it to 0.8 it works but it doesn't fit on the page but if I multiply with and height as you suggested with 1.25 it fits on the page but its 1cm big and not 0.8 anymore.

Comment: @Katharina My bad! You need to multiply `xmax` and `ymax` also by `1.25`. I edited my answer accordingly. Sorry.